# javascript - oAuth: How to redirect user back to application?

Tags: javascript, redirect, oauth-2.0, oauth, auth0

I am new to javascript. I'm creating a login webpage with auth0, if the user enters the correct id/password the auth0 login API will redirect them back to the application, they are calling from based on their redirect URL.

I want to add a feature where if they don't accept terms and conditions, they would be redirected back to the application they are calling from via redirect URL.

Is it possible? I tried to search online but could not find any proper documentation.  can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to user callback URLs with the error message.

Solution for this in Vue.js

```
<a v-on:click="f1()">..</a>

 f1: function() {
       window.location.href = "myapp://callback?error=MyCustoomrErrorMessage";
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't there be any param in the URL when they get directed to your application? i think there should be a param in the URL that you can use to redirect them back.